# What exactly is DOM Load time?

Tags: javascript, dom

What exactly is DOM Load time?
Is it time to just get complete html from server   or does it include the rendering time?
Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly speaking, load time includes:

- Getting all markup, replaced element
  content and embeds from server
- Parsing the markup
- Applying the CSS cascade to the
  markup
- Rendering the page
- Running all scripts that need to run
  on page load (which may include
  scripts that get more content and
  cause further parsing and rendering)

From the user's point of view, load time is the time between navigating to a page and being able to access, visually and every other way, the finished output.

Comment: Doesn't the "load" event also wait for images?

Comment: So is Page load time and DOM load time represent the same?

Comment: @Pointy: images are replaced elements.